# Range function Python

Tags: python

i'm new to Python but learning with up's and downs.

I don't understand this bit of code:

To iterate over the indices of a sequence, combine range() and len() as follows:

```
>>> a = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...     print i, a[i]
... 
0 Mary
1 had
2 a
3 little
4 lamb
```

Pretty straight forward. But i don't see in `print i, a[i]` where the extra `[i]` comes into play. (Due to my little knowledge of python, no doubt).
But if somebody's willing to nudge me in the right direction, i'd be very happy.

Comment: who/whatever told you to do this should really have told you about `enumerate`.

Comment: @roippi: to be fair, that's the example in the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).  The same section says "In most such cases, however, it is convenient to use the enumerate() function, see Looping Techniques."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. The `[i]` is an index - recall from section 3 of the tutorial that you had `word = HelpA` resulting in `word[4] = A`. That's because when you used the index 4 there, you asked for the element in position `4` in `word`. (Also remember that the leftmost element is in position 0, so `word[0] = H`, `word[1]=e`, `word[2]=l`, `word[3]=p`, `word[4]=A`).

Comment: @amp thank you for the tips. @ all, thank you guys for explaining what it actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down.

#### The `for` loop

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
```

- `len(a)` returns an `int` equal to the length of list `a`. Let's call this integer `b`, `b = len(a)`
- `range(b)` returns a list of `ints` from `0` to `b - 1`, e.g., `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The `for` loop iterates over the list returned by `range()` and assigns the current value to `i` (you could call this `whatever`)

Example:

```
>>> for whatever in range(len(a)):
...    print whatever, a[whatever]
```

#### the `print` statement

```
...    print i, a[i]
```

Then you print `i` followed by the value of list `a` at index `i`

---

You could also use the `enumerate` function as others have suggested:

```
for key, value in enumerate(a)
    print key, value
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down for me. Now it's clear for me how i should read and interpret this code. I'll also take a look at enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` is an integer, `a[i]` is retrieving the ith element from the list `a`. An easy way to see this -- as pointed out by @DSM -- is to compare what would be output if you did not use `[i]`:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...    print i, a
0 ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
1 ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
2 ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
3 ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
4 ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
```

Instead of printing a single value at each iteration, you are printing out the entire list.

Note that you can achieve the same functionality more concisely using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> for i, w in enumerate(a):
...    print i, w
0 Mary
1 had
2 a
3 little
4 lamb
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what `a[i]` does, which is the question.  The OP can compare the two by comparing `print i, a` with `print i, a[i]`.

Comment: @DSM: thanks for the feedback. I think your idea to compare the two helps makes the functionality clearer, so I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first of all if you want to get an index and a value in a loop use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for k, v in emumerate(a):
    print k, v
```

In your case no extra "[i]" in your sample. `len(a)` returns `5`.

`range(5)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Assuming that indexes starts with 0 everything is correct.